# Accidentally drop 'performance_schema' of MySQL

Tags: mysql

Now i cannot connect to MySQL server. It keeps showing error "Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist". I tried to reinstall MySQL workbench like 50 times but nothing works. How can i fix this ?

Comment: what does mySQL workbench has to do with mysql server ? try reinstalling mysql server instead

Comment: i just only install mysql workbench to work